# Doctrine Entity findBy Many to Many

Tags: symfony1, doctrine-orm

I have a many to many relationship between products and colours.

What I am trying to do is find products by their colours.

eg)

```
$colours = $em->getRepository('Xxxxx\XxxxxBundle\Entity\Colour')->findBy(array('name'=>'red');
$products = $em->getRepository('Xxxxx\XxxxxBundle\Entity\Product')->findBy(array('colours'=>$colours));
```

This is my Yaml config:

```
Xxxxx\XxxxxBundle\Entity\Product:
  type: entity
  manyToMany:
    colours:
      targetEntity: Colour
      joinTable:
        name: Product_Colour
        joinColumns:
          product_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
        inverseJoinColumns:
          colour_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
```

.

```
 Xxxxx\XxxxxBundle\Entity\Colour:
  type: entity
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    hex:
      type: string
      length: 320
    name:
      type: string
      length: 320
```

The error message I am getting is:

```
Notice: Undefined index: joinColumns in /home/xxx/public_html/products/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php line 1217
```

Would someone be able to shine some light on why this is not working.

Answer (score 11):

I know this is an old question, but if anyone else arrives here via Google (like I did), I had to eschew the findBy and use DQL in the repository:

```
$products = $em->getRepository('Vendor\Bundle\Entity\Product')->findByColours($colours);
```

And in the repository:

```
public function findByColours($colours)
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb ->select(array('p'))
        ->from('VendorBundle:Product', 'p')
        ->join('p.colours', 'c', 'WITH', $qb->expr()->in('c.id', $colours));
    $result = $qb->getQuery()->execute();
    return $result;

}
```

You may need to change the join based on what $colours is. This is assuming it's an array of colour IDs. If it's a string you can forgo the `in()` or if it's an array of strings you'll need to bind the strings as parameters (see the following link). Clarification on expr() and such is in the [Doctrine docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class)

I don't know why `Undefined index: joinColumns` occurs, but this is a method to side-step it altogether. Hopefully someone can clarify as to the error, as my solution adds extra work to the Many to Many relationship.